# How to add a few navigation links to every slide in Reveal js

Tags: javascript, reveal.js

I want to add some navigation links to every slide in reveal.js. Using the solution given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25479420/fixed-footer-on-all-slides-in-reveal-js%60) I can easily add a text footer. However, if the footer div contains a hyperlink (please see the code below) nothing happens when the link is clicked. Can someone please explain why that is the case and how I need to modify the code so that the link works?

Thank you.

**The code that does not work**

```
    <div class="footer">
        <a href="http://www.google.com" id="noteslink">TOC</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think I figured this out. It appears that elements are layered in RevealJS and the link was not at the top layer. That is, some invisible element was covering it up, and hence the link was not clickable, and did not work. I added the z-index property with z-index of 100 to the footer class and now the link works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It might be blocking non HTTP requests. try

a href="https://www.google.com" id="noteslink">TOC

Comment: I updated the post. I did write `http://www.google.com` and `https://www.google.com` in my code. That does not work either. I also tried your solution, and that does not work